# Stuck between ANOVA (with transformation) and multinomial logistic regression

Tags: biostatistics

I need help in determining the appropriate stat test to use. I want to know if the 5 treatments (including the control variable) has significant differences based on their Antioxidant Activity as Gallic Acid (%w/w). Here is the data:

[image: My data]

Comment: Why logistic regression? Your dependent variable seems to be continuous.

Comment: Well, you can disregard that thought.I'm just trying to find out what appropriate test that needs to be used

Comment: But, based on your comment, you are considering only one test then!  There seems to be no question left to answer.

Answer (score 0):

A regression with just categorical independent variables is basically just an ANOVA, because both underlies a t-distribution for calculating the significance ( in case of regression of the coefficients). In both cases, residuals should be (approximately) be normally distributed. So both ways are fine.